# Return same position for similar values in a list

Tags: python

I have sorted a list in descending order, I am trying to find a way in which similar numbers re-appearing in the list will return equal position and the next unique number to return the next position. Example in this `samplelist = [50, 40, 40, 30, 30, 20, 10]`  50 should return 1, 40 returns 2, next 40 returns 2, 30 returns 4, next 30 returns 4 then 20 returns 6, 10 returns 7. Note that this will be a dynamic list. This is how far I have gone but it isn't quite right.

```
samplelist = [10, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 50]
samplelist.sort(reverse=True)
print(samplelist)
appearances = {}
for index, value in enumerate(samplelist):
    appearances[value] = samplelist.count(value)
for index, value in enumerate(appearances.items()):
    print(f'Position for {value[0]} = {index + value[1]}')
```

Comment: Note that the built-in [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) does exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be done using just the `list.index` utility in python, which gives the index of the first occurrence of an element.

So, your program must do this :

```
appearances[value] = samplelist.index(value)
```

instead of this :

```
appearances[value] = samplelist.count(value) # It just returns the count of the value in samplelist
```

Answer (score 1):

you can store the index of first appearances in samplelist to appearances dictionary by adding 1 to it. so that the dictionary will contain all the unique elements with there index of first appearnances. Then you can print elements from samplelist and get there indexs from dictionary.
have a look at this code.

```
samplelist = [10, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 50]
samplelist.sort(reverse=True)
appearances = {}
for index, value in enumerate(samplelist):
    appearances[value] = samplelist.index(value)+1
for index, value in enumerate(samplelist):
    print(f'Position for {value} = {appearances[value]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You always override old values with new ones therefore check if value is present in dictionary before insert. Also you should use `index` instead of `count` to find index of element

```py
samplelist = [10, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 50]
samplelist.sort(reverse=True)
print(samplelist)
appearances = {}
for index, value in enumerate(samplelist):
    if not value in appearances:
        appearances[value] = samplelist.index(value)
for index, value in enumerate(appearances.items()):
    print(f'Position for {value[0]} = {index + value[1]}')
```

Btw, you already got index inside `index` variable, so you don't need to find index of element `appearances[value] = index`